# Graphics.py: Check if point is in Object

Tags: python, graphics

In short, I want to make a radar of sorts, using specifically the graphics.py library, that detects if pre-drawn Shape exists at a Point.

Below I've drafted up a code that will show me all the points within a radar (and return it as an array), but I want to be able to take a point/coordinate and check if it is inside a Circle or Rectangle etc *without* knowing anything else (i.e only x and y parameters, no knowledge of other existing Shapes). Something like:

```
if Point(x,y).getObject() is None:
    return False
```

or even

```
if Point(x,y).getObject().config["fill"] == "#f00":
    return True
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
from graphics import *

def getAllPointsInRadius(circle, win):

    cx = int(circle.getCenter().getX())
    cy = int(circle.getCenter().getY())
    r = circle.getRadius()# + 2
    points = []
    print cx, cy

    for i in range(cx-r, cx+r):
        for j in range(cy-r, cy+r):
            x = i-circle.getRadius()
            y = j - circle.getRadius()

            if ((i - cx) * (i - cx) + (j - cy) * (j - cy) <= r * r):
                points.append(Point(i,j)) #if within, append as Point
                p = Point(i, j)
                p.setFill('#551A8B')
                p.draw(win) #illustrate all points inside radar
            else:
                p = Point(i, j)
                p.setFill('#0000ff')
                p.draw(win) #points outside

    return points

win = GraphWin('Radar', width = 500, height = 500)
win.setCoords(0, 0, 30, 30)
win.setBackground('black')

#object to be detected
objectCircle = Circle(Point(11, 12), 2)
objectCircle.setFill('#f00')
objectCircle.draw(win)

#radius within objects may be detected
radiusCircle = Circle(Point(10, 10), 3)
radiusCircle.setOutline('#fff')
radiusCircle.draw(win)

print getAllPointsInRadius(radiusCircle, win)


#print Point(11, 12).config["outline"]

win.getMouse()
```

Addendum: I think maybe by making Point(x,y) I'm actually creating a point and not returning the coordinates. I'm not sure how to do it otherwise, though.

Comment: A point is inside a circle if its cartesian distance from the center of the circle is less than the circle's radius.  There is a library function math.hypot that helps with this little calculation.

Comment: I understand that, but thing is, that's assuming I know both the specific circle/point I'm looking for. I want to know _if_ something exists inside the circle/radar. Could be a Rectangle, Circle, Polygon.

Comment: Whatever that "thing" is, it must have geometrical coordinates.  And you must know those coordinates or else you can't do anything.  Figuring out if those coordinates lie inside or outside the circle is still the same calculation.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Essentially that's it. I guess it boils down to: pick any point, check if shape is drawn there. (Checking if it's in or outside the radius can be set aside for now).

Comment: I would look at it as a math problem first and a programming problem second.  There's a formula to determine if a point is inside a circle, another for whether one circle is inside another, and a third one for whether a rectangle is in a circle.  In your example you construct a list of all the points in a circle but that doesn't seem necessary (plus slow and inefficient).  Good luck.